# Unable to set iskeyword for colon ( : ) character

Tags: cursor-motions, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex, keyword

I am using vim to edit LaTeX files.

Throughout the text, there are labels to equations, tables etc. for which an accepted convention among TeX writers is the following

`\label{eq:massenergy}` , `\label{tbl:exptresults}` etc.

These can be cross-referenced later in text, eg `referring to equation~\ref{eq:massenergy}, we can see that ..... blah ...blah ...`

Sometimes, I want to change the equation being referenced, say I want to replace `{eq:massenergy}` with `{eq:workenergyequivalence}`. If my cursor is already somewhere in the word  `massenergy`, I can do `ciw` and start typing the desired label. But in this case, it deletes the entire content within braces, i.e. becomes equivalent to `ci}`.

**How can I set `:` as a word separator?** Note that `iskeyword+=:` did not make any difference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for

```
set iskeyword-=:
```

That is, making `:` explicitly *not* a keyword character.  If `:` is in `iskeyword` it will be included in `ciw`.